# Change Pandas column value by checking multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Dataframe `df`

```
    Name  Age   Salary
0    Tom   28     100
1   Jack   34     200
2    Tom   28     100
3   Jack   34     200
4  Harry   36     300
5  Harry   36     300
```

and I have a Numpy array of name `name_array=['Tom', 'Jack', 'Harry']`. I have another 
Numpy array name `increment_array=[10,20,30]`

What I want is

```
    Name  Age   Salary
0    Tom   28     1000
1   Jack   34     4000
2    Tom   28     1000
3   Jack   34     4000
4  Harry   36     9000
5  Harry   36     9000
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use map:

```
name_array = ['Tom', 'Jack', 'Harry']
increment_array = [10, 20, 30]

lookup = dict(zip(name_array, increment_array))

df['Salary'] = df.Name.map(lookup) * df.Salary

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    Name  Age  Salary
0    Tom   28    1000
1   Jack   34    4000
2    Tom   28    1000
3   Jack   34    4000
4  Harry   36    9000
5  Harry   36    9000
```